# MySQL Connector Linker Problem

Tags: c++, netbeans, mysql-connector

Hey, I'm trying to compile a program with the MySQL C++ Connector but somehow I can't get the linking right.

The errors I get are:

```
mysql/lib/libmysqlcppconn.so: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::ios_base()@GLIBCPP_3.2'.... etc
```

[alt text http://img156.imageshack.us/img156/4022/linking.th.png](http://img156.imageshack.us/img156/4022/linking.png)

**locations:**

> libmysqlcppconn.so: mysql/lib/
>
> libmysqlclient.so:  /usr/lib/

I tried to follow the tutorial on mysql and some other pages but the results where the same, maybe I missed something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it seems like the connector (binary) requires a certain libstdc++.so version (5) since I couldn't fix that I had to use the sources. Some errors I encountered while compiling them where that I had to include `<stdio.h>`. Now Everything is working!